# how to stop & signs going through ajax, but keeping them as text

Tags: jquery, ajax, sanitization

I have a comment form that submits through ajax,

Here is the ajax code

```
$('#button').click(function(){ 
    comment = $('#comment').val();
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : '/ajax/comment.php',
        data    : 'comment='+comment,
        success : function(data) {
             $('#comment_update').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is, if someone comments something like this 'this comment & this comment', then the & will make the POST think there is an extra variable, and thus cut the comment to 'this comment ' and leave the rest. Is there some sort of sanitization I am supposed to do here? Or how else can the full string go through if '&' is within it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a json data type and modifying the data attribute accordingly;

```
dataType: "json",
data: {
 comment: comment,
 morestuff: morestuff
},
```

Sorry I have not referenced this, I was just here for the unicorns.